# Python program works only for few seconds and crashes

Tags: python

Hey Recently I have a problem with my python program. After launching it works for a few seconds and says "Not responding". This is macro like program and code works but not with the window rendering. When I mark the code that detects scroll as comment program is properly rendering but is useless. Here is my code

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import os
import pyglet
import pyglet.window.key
width = 600
height = 500
canchange = 1
togled = 0
title = "ScrollClick by Pouek_"
window = pyglet.window.Window(width, height, title) 
text = "ScrollClick"
Scrolled = "Don't worry now. It's working I promise"
etc = "Made by Pouek_ @2020"
mouse = Controller()

while True:  
    try:  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('t'): 
            if canchange == 1 & togled == 1:
                canchange = 0
                togled = 0
                print("Toggled of")
            if canchange == 1 & togled == 0:
                canchange = 0
                togled = 1
                print("Toggled on")

            break  
    except:
        break

if canchange == 0:
    sleep(0.5)
    canchange = 1

label3 = pyglet.text.Label(etc, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//1.25, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 36, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//2, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 
  
new_label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

new_label2 = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

label2 = pyglet.text.Label(Scrolled, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//10, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

@window.event 
def on_draw():      
    window.clear() 
    label3.draw()
    label.draw() 
    label2.draw()

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if togled == 1:
        print('Mouse scrolled at ({0}, {1})({2}, {3})'.format(x, y, dx, dy))
        print("Mouse scrolled")
        mouse.press(Button.right)
        mouse.release(Button.right)
        mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_move=None, on_click=None, on_scroll=on_scroll)
        mouse_listener.start()
        mouse_listener.join()

mouse = Controller()
print ("Current position: " + str(mouse.position))
#os.system("1.py")
img = image = pyglet.resource.image("logo.png")
window.set_icon(img)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Thanks for help

Comment: you never exit the while loop unless t is pressed

Comment: Maybe adding some delay to the while True loop could help

Comment: Also, just as an FYI, using `time.sleep` inside of a program that handles a GUI could make the program to "not repsond" during the sleep-time. If the `sleep` condition is constantly hit, then there will not be enough time for the program itself to do anything.

Comment: I have kind off fixed my problem but I still have one question. How I can detect a keypress in better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue and realised that this project is unstable.
Here is how I did it.
First I made second file with this code and named it 1.py

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
import os
def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Mouse scrolled at ({0}, {1})({2}, {3})'.format(x, y, dx, dy))
    print("Mouse scrolled")
    mouse.press(Button.right)
    mouse.release(Button.right)
mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_move=None, on_click=None, on_scroll=on_scroll)
mouse = Controller()
mouse_listener.start()
mouse_listener.join()
```

Then I got rid of the key activation feature and changed the code from this

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import os
import pyglet
import pyglet.window.key
width = 600
height = 500
canchange = 1
togled = 0
title = "ScrollClick by Pouek_"
window = pyglet.window.Window(width, height, title) 
text = "ScrollClick"
Scrolled = "Don't worry now. It's working I promise"
etc = "Made by Pouek_ @2020"
mouse = Controller()

while True:  
    try:  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('t'): 
            if canchange == 1 & togled == 1:
                canchange = 0
                togled = 0
                print("Toggled of")
            if canchange == 1 & togled == 0:
                canchange = 0
                togled = 1
                print("Toggled on")

            break  
    except:
        break

if canchange == 0:
    sleep(0.5)
    canchange = 1

label3 = pyglet.text.Label(etc, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//1.25, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 36, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//2, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 
  
new_label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

new_label2 = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

label2 = pyglet.text.Label(Scrolled, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//10, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

@window.event 
def on_draw():      
    window.clear() 
    label3.draw()
    label.draw() 
    label2.draw()

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if togled == 1:
        print('Mouse scrolled at ({0}, {1})({2}, {3})'.format(x, y, dx, dy))
        print("Mouse scrolled")
        mouse.press(Button.right)
        mouse.release(Button.right)
        mouse_listener = MouseListener(on_move=None, on_click=None, on_scroll=on_scroll)
        mouse_listener.start()
        mouse_listener.join()

mouse = Controller()
print ("Current position: " + str(mouse.position))
#os.system("1.py")
img = image = pyglet.resource.image("logo.png")
window.set_icon(img)
pyglet.app.run()
```

To this

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import os
import pyglet
import pyglet.window.key
width = 600
height = 500
title = "ScrollClick by Pouek_"
window = pyglet.window.Window(width, height, title) 
text = "ScrollClick"
Scrolled = "Don't worry now. It's working I promise"
etc = "Made by Pouek_ @2020"
mouse = Controller()

label3 = pyglet.text.Label(etc, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//1.25, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 36, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//2, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 
  
new_label = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

new_label2 = pyglet.text.Label(text, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 10, 
                          x = 25, y = 25) 

label2 = pyglet.text.Label(Scrolled, 
                          font_name ='Times New Roman', 
                          font_size = 24, 
                          x = window.width//2, y = window.height//10, 
                          anchor_x ='center', anchor_y ='center') 

@window.event 
def on_draw():      
    window.clear() 
    label3.draw()
    label.draw() 
    label2.draw()

mouse = Controller()
print ("Current position: " + str(mouse.position))
img = image = pyglet.resource.image("logo.png")
window.set_icon(img)
pyglet.app.run() 
os.system("1.py")
```

When I run the program everything worked but the macro was too fast that I needed to turn off the program with task manager. If you want to modify this you can but it's very fast and not very effective. Also thanks for comments. They helped me a lot :)